# Getting started with the SBT Java EE samples

Tags: java, tomcat, ibm-sbt

I have connected my Eclipse and cloned the https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK.git

I have a Tomcat 7.0 server and the SBT properties file

I have added the following web projects to the server:

`com.ibm.sbt.bootstrap211
com.ibm.sbt.sample.web
com.ibm.sbt.web`

When I open de sample web (`http://localhost:8080/sbt.sample.web/home.jsp`) 
I get the page, but selecting a environment does not result in any change.
Which means that the pages remain empty...

The question is: can someone point me to a document or youtube movie that explains al this (I already have the labs PDF) but I want to get started with the latest build.

Answer (score 1):

There should also be a JavaScript and a Java link on the header of that page.

There is a issue with the layout by which these two item disappear if the window is too narrow... you might try enlarging the window more than the screen or just deep linking to the samples in

```
http://localhost:8080/sbt.sample.web/java.jsp
```

for some of the samples, especially those using oauth, you will need to use your real machine address and the https protocol on port 8443.

Comment: you can also try https and port 8443... also sometimes it take a few minutes for Tomcat to fully extract sbt.sample.web. (I had this when I was starting tomcat up for the first time and doing a backup) you may want to shut it down and restart it.